# Redux: turn middleware on and off

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, middleware

I am looking for a way to turn a middleware on and off. I introduced a tutorial functionality - I listen to what the user is doing with the UI by checking each action with a "guidance" middleware. if the user clicks  on the right place he moves to the next step in the tutorial. However this behaviour is only needed when the tutorial mode is on. Any ideas?

```
const store = createStore(holoApp, compose(applyMiddleware(timestamp, ReduxThunk, autosave, guidance),
window.devToolsExtension ? window.devToolsExtension() : f => f));
```

for now my solution was to keep the "on" switch in a guidanceState reducer and dirty check it in the middleware:

```
const guidance = store => next => action => {

    let result = next(action)

    const state = store.getState();
    const { guidanceState } = state;
    const { on } = guidanceState;

    if (on) {

 ....
```

However, ~95% of the time the tutorial mode would be off so dirty checking every action all the time feels a bit, well, dirty... ;) Any other ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do stateful things in middleware (unless you have a good pattern for managing that state, like Sagas).  Don't do stateful things with your middleware stack at all if you can avoid it.  (If you *must* do so, [@TimoSta's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40385933/135978) is the correct one).

Instead, manage your tours with a reducer:

```
const finalReducer = combineReducers({
  // Your other reducers
  tourState: tourReducer
});

function tourReducer(state = initalTourState, action) {
  switch(action.type) {
    case TOUR_LAST_STEP:
      return /* compose next tour step state here */;
    case TOUR_NEXT_STEP:
      return /* compose last tour step state here */;
    case TOUR_CLOSE:
      return undefined; // Nothing to do in this case
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Then, in your application use the current state of `tourState` to move the highlighting, and if there is nothing in `tourState`, turn the tour off.

```
store.subscribe(() => {
  const state = store.getState();
  if (state.tourState) {
    tourManager.setTourStep(state.tourState);
  } else {
    tourManager.close();
  }
});
```

You don't have to use a stateful tour manager either - if you're using React it could just be a component that pulls out `tourState` with a `connect` wrapper and renders `null` if there is no state:

```
// waves hands vigorously
const TourComponent = (props) => {
  if (props.currentStep) return <TourStep ...props.currentStep />;
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it mean I still dirty check each action in the subscribe callback? I am now thinking how can I combine your suggestion with a way to subscribe and unsubscribe on tutorial start and end.

Comment: Ok, ended up using a route {path: '/session/:sessionId/tutorial', component: App, onEnter: tutorialEnter} mixed with subscribe

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any way to replace middlewares on the fly via redux's API.

Instead, you could create a completely new store with the old store's state as initial state and the new set of middlewares. This may work seamlessly with your application.

Comment: That can be a clever way. However I still need to somehow spot the moment the tutorial starts and create a new store. How would you go about it?

Comment: Ok, ended up using a route
{path: '/session/:sessionId/tutorial', component: App, onEnter: tutorialEnter}

Answer (score 1):

Three ideas you could consider:

- Have the middleware listen for "GUIDANCE_START" and "GUIDANCE_STOP" actions.  When those come through, update some behavior, and don't actually pass them to `next`.
- You could write a middleware that constructs its own middleware pipeline internally, and dynamically adds and removes the guidance middleware as needed (somewhat related discussion at [replaceMiddleware feature for use with lazy-loaded modules](https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/2041))
- This might be a good use case for something like a saga, rather than a middleware.  I know I've seen discussions of using sagas for onboarding workflows, such as the [Key&Pad app](http://keyandpad.com/) (source:[key-and-pad](https://github.com/joshwcomeau/key-and-pad/blob/master/src/sagas/onboarding.saga.js#L47-L75))